# Rendering does not reflect the new rotation of my character after using Blender's Python API's rotation_euler function

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, transforms

Want to render a character in different direction using scripts, set the character standing on a plane, and use the code like following:

```
for i in range(0, 8):
    model.rotation_euler = (0,0,2 * pi * i / 8)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

But in rendered image the character is lying on the plane, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your scene using `bpy.context.scene.update()` and you should get the result that you expect.

So your code should look like this:

```
for i in range(0, 8):
    model.rotation_euler = (0,0,2 * pi * i / 8)
    bpy.context.scene.update()
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work

Comment: I solved the problem. It might have something to do with local axis and global axis, change the code to model.rotation_euler = (pi/2,0,2 * pi * i / len(direction)) solve it